# Why addClass() is not working? Use mCustomScrollbar

Tags: javascript, mcustomscrollbar

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mnnpgt/)

**HTML**

```
<ul class="menu" data-mcs-theme="dark">
  <li><a href="#" id="view-all">View All</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li> 
  <li><a href="#">Test</a></li>  
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.menu {
    height: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('#view-all').click(function(){
   $('.menu').addClass('mCustomScrollbar');
});
```

When I click on 'View All' the JS add class 'mCustomScrollbar' but custome scroll dosn't work?
Тhanks to all in advance!

Comment: You didn't give us code for class custom scrollbar.

Comment: You have to initiate the scrollbar like:  `$(".menu").mCustomScrollbar();`

Comment: I add the mCustomScrollbar.css! 
Thanks to all again!

Comment: @SujataChanda it works well thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Initiate the scrollbar, like this:-

```
$('#view-all').click(function(){
    $(".menu").mCustomScrollbar();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9mnnpgt/1/)